# How do you build a portable lightweight frame for trees?

Tags: pvc, structural, gardening

I have fruit trees that vary in size that need frost protection in the winter and bird protection in the summer. I have been hanging frost cloth and bird netting over the trees using the branches as support. That is not always effective for various reasons and so I want to build some frames that will stand over the trees over which I can drape the frost cloth or bird netting.

The structure/frame does not need to be more than 8 feet tall and around 4 to 5 feet wide.

What materials would be best to create this and how would I assemble it?

Additional considerations:

- Location: Phoenix, AZ
- The frames need to be portable and can't be fixed in the ground.
- Would be amazing if the height and width could be adjusted but I feel that this is an elaborate and non-essential requirement.
- Need to be able to "stake" the frame during monsoon season.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PVC pipe might be a fairly cheap option.  Though exposure to UV will reduce its impact resistance over time, so you might have to replace parts over the years.

If you dry fit the fittings, you can assemble/disassemble as needed. Which would reduce the space required for storage, and increase portability.

You might have to use sandbags or stakes to keep them in place, if it's windy in your area.